# Converting Month Number to Month Name in Python

Tags: python, date

I am trying to convert the current month number to the month name. I have read similar threads, but I am getting an error when I try the conventional method and I don't know what is causing the error. Here is my code:

```
month_name = datetime.now().month

month_name.strftime("%B")
```

And I am getting this error:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [202], in <cell line: 2>()
      1 month_name = datetime.now().month
----> 2 month_name.strftime("%B")

AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'strftime'.
```

​
How can I fix this?

Comment: `datetime` objects have `strftime` methods, not integers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to store the date corresponding to the month you are getting from `datetime.now()`:

```
from datetime import datetime

date = datetime.now()
month_number = date.month

print(date.strftime("%B"), month_number)
```

**Output:**

```
June 6
```